# Trouble Understanding jQuery-UI Popup Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-menu

I'm trying to figure out how to make a pop-up menu using the jQuery UI menu widget.

After searching around, I finally found the following demo that does what I want:

http://view.jqueryui.com/menubar/demos/popup/popup-menu.html

However, I am having a little trouble understanding this demo. For example:

1. What is making the menu hidden before any of the buttons are clicked?
2. What is causing the menu to close when it's open and I click somewhere else on the page?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: `What is making the menu hidden` Well, of course it is the jQuery UI making it hidden.

Comment: Was this intended to be helpful? Which jQuery UI function hides it and where does it get called?

Comment: `Line 25: $("#button1").button().next().menu(...` It makes `#button1` a button, and make the next element the `menu`.

Comment: I can see it makes the button a trigger and the list the menu. But I don't see how that's related to what I asked.

Comment: When you call `.menu()`, it triggers many things including hiding the menu and adding listeners, for example, it applies class names to the target element `line 45@jquery.ui.menu.js ...addClass( "ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this may be what you're looking for. When you call `.menu()`, lots of things are triggered in the `_create()` function (as Derek said), like setting class names etc. Then, at lines 123-135 in `jquery.ui.menu.js`, this happens:

```
    this.refresh();

    // Clicks outside of a menu collapse any open menus
    this._on( this.document, {
        click: function( event ) {
            if ( !$( event.target ).closest( ".ui-menu" ).length ) {
                this.collapseAll( event );
            }

            // Reset the mouseHandled flag
            mouseHandled = false;
        }
    });
```

The second part makes sure all menus are collapsed when the user clicks on the page (`this.document`) outside a menu (`.ui-menu`): `this.collapseAll()` is called, which calls `this._close()`, which in turn calls `hide()`. This should answer your second question.

As for your first question, The first thing the `refresh()` function does is:

```
    // Initialize nested menus
    var menus,
        icon = this.options.icons.submenu,
        submenus = this.element.find( this.options.menus + ":not(.ui-menu)" )
            .addClass( "ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" )
            .hide()
            .attr({
                role: this.options.role,
                "aria-hidden": "true",
                "aria-expanded": "false"
            });
```

This finds all submenus not previously initialized (in this case all of them since we're coming from `_create()`) and initializes them, which includes hiding them.

Comment: None of this actually hides the menu itself, it only deals with submenus.

Answer (score 2):

That demo uses a modified version of jquery.ui.menu.js along with the popup widget: http://view.jqueryui.com/menubar/ui/jquery.ui.popup.js

Menu itself, as released in 1.9, doesn't have any code for showing it as a popup. I recommend writing some custom code to build a popup menu, until a stable release offers a proper solution.

Answer (score 2):

The [jQuery UI Popup - Popup Menu](http://view.jqueryui.com/menubar/demos/popup/popup-menu.html) you referenced uses [unreleased code](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8235) as [Jörn Zaefferer](http://bassistance.de/) said. (Notice that Jörn is the same guy that closed [the bug](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8235))

But there is an almost identical-looking solution in [jQuery UI Button's Split Button example](http://jqueryui.com/button/#splitbutton) that *doesn't* use `.popup()` and does all the hiding etc. explicitly.

Perhaps you could use that as a starting point instead. I know I'm going to! ;-)